# Trying to learn javascript. Working on retirement calculator. Need Loop advice

Tags: javascript, loops, calculator

**Update I have chance previous variable to return a value. I still have no solution for the loop error. When I submit it returns $5.1572...., when it should be returning around 200k. **

I have a retirement calculator that I have created for some online classes and I cannot get the loop to work. I assume that's what it is.

I have verified that the calculator is working and have no other errors but just don't seem to understand how to use the loop properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Trying to take `retire` (age) - `current` (age) to come up with `lengthOfCalulation`. From there I need to take the `Return` (% of interest) and the `PerYear` ($ of investment each year) and determine the future value.

```
function Savings() {
    var Current  = Number(document.getElementById('AgeNow').value); 
    var Retire = Number(document.getElementById('AgeThen').value); 
    var Return = Number(document.getElementById('Return').value); 
    var PerYear = Number(document.getElementById('PerYear').value); 
    var lengthOfCalculation = Retire - Current; 
    var results;
    var total = 0;

    for (results=0; results < lengthOfCalculation; results++) {
        total = (total + PerYear) * (1 + Return);
    }
    alert("When you retire your account will have $" + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Did you open your eyes before submitting this question?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Did you see the [original revision](http://i.stack.imgur.com/58FfD.png)?

Comment: doesnt have a closing curly brace, or is it a typo?

Comment: Apologies, I didnt realize I submitted it as question. I corrected the curly brace @brenners1302, just a typo.

Comment: have you tried checking if the variables have expected values?

Comment: @brenners1302 yes, I just ran through them all and tested each one. The value returned was the input value.

Comment: The function isn't returning a value, and you're re-declaring `total` for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: (noticed late haha)whats the use of the loop if you dont use the "results" inside loop?You are just iterating the equation but it will only result in same answer.

Comment: Placing total together with the Per year variable and multiplying it to the interest will surely decrease the expected value. Can you give us sample data and expected results so that we can formulate an equation from that.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the variable total in each iteration and you are not using your results variable in your calculation in the loop. This loop just calculates the same result each time so it would be the same without looping at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function Savings() {
var Current  = Number(document.myForm.AgeNow.value); 
var Retire = Number(document.myForm.AgeThen.value); 
var Return = Number(document.myForm.Return.value); 
var PerYear = Number(document.myForm.PerYear.value); 
var lengthOfCalculation = Retire - Current; 
var results;
var total = 0;

for (results=0; results < lengthOfCalculation; results++) {
     total += (PerYear  * (1 + Return));
}
alert("When you retire your account will have $" + total.toFixed(2));
```

}

Comment: I tried using this but I am still coming up with the incorrect answer. I don't know any better so its hard to speculate but it seems like something is off in the for statement. My result is coming in at about 3x the amount it should be. I verified all the variables to ensure they are coming through again and no issues.

Comment: can you post a sample data and expected result?